# ffbase package fails to load

Tags: r, package, bigdata, ffbase

I have just installed the **ff** and **ffbase** packages in R, and while `library(ff)` works, `library(ffbase)` returns the following error:

```
> library(ffbase)
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  DLL ‘fastmatch’ not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ffbase’
```

I use the latest version R  3.0.2.
Any help how I can fix that error will be appreciated dearly. I have uninstalled R and reinstalled everything, to no avail.

Comment: fastmatch is a dependency of ffbase. So install it first. `install.packages("fastmatch")`

Comment: @jwijffels Works brilliantly, thanks!